# How to merge commits till a certain point

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 2 branches master staging, assuming I have 10 commits in master after I merged to staging a while ago. Now I would like to merge only the first 5 commits out of 10 into staging branch. How do I specify that in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, look through your commit history, and get the commit you want to merge from the master branch, you should see something like this:

```
$> git log
[...]
commit c5960dbe4674ae72f80cbe1ed5eb0cc690062c7a
Author: (...)
Date:   Mon Nov 18 11:42:58 2013 +0100

this is a commit message!
[...]
```

now switch to your staging branch and run

```
$> git merge <commit-id>
```

If you didn't do anything weird, git should be able to fast forward this, and you're done.

Comment: I am assuming it would be upto this commit-id correct?

Comment: @Rpj up to and including.